# c++ Explicit specialization doesn't work correctly VS Studio

Tags: templates, visual-c++

I work in Visual Studio 2017 and noticed an error at compilation

```
template<class T>T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a + b;
};

template<> Line add<Line, Point>(Line line, Point point) /*E0493 there are 
no instances of the "add" function pattern corresponding to the specified  
type*/ 
{
    Line newline;
    newline.start = add(point, line.start);
    newline.end = add(point, line.end);
    return newline;
}
template<> Point add<Point, Point>(Point a, Point b)//here is the same
{
    Point res;
    res.x = a.x + b.x;
    res.y = a.y + b.y;
    return res;
}
```

I tried to erase "template<>" before the 2nd and 3rd implementations of add()function and code worked fine. But i want to understand why this code doesn't work in my VS Studio 2017.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for a function template specialization would be

```
template<> Point add(Point a, Point b) { ... }
```

However, `add(Line, Point)` cannot possibly be a specialization of the primary template `template<class T> T add(T a, T b)`, as the latter expects two parameters of the same type.